# Why does req.body keep returning an empty object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

req.body keeps returning an empty object no matter what I do,

I've tried

```
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
```

and then adding jsonParser to function -> app.post('/api/get-last-project',jsonParser,(req, res) => {
and

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

and

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

here is where i recieve it,

```
app.post('/api/get-last-project',(req, res) => {
var theProject;
  var theQuestions;
  var theAnswers;
  var qp;
  projectModel.findOne().sort({date: -1}).exec(function(err, doc) {
      if(!err)
      {
        if(doc)
        {
          console.log("hitta");
          theProject = doc;
          theQuestions = doc.questions.map(question => {
            questionModel.findById(question._id);
            theAnswers.push(question.answerIds.map(answer => {
              answerModel.findById(answer._id);
            }))
          })
          qp = questionPackageModel.findOne(projectId = doc._id);
          res.send(fetchedMaterial = {theProject, theQuestions, theAnswers, qp});
        }
        else{
          console.log("skapa");
          console.log(req.body)  //here it logs {} no matter what I do..
          createdMaterial = createProject.create(req.body);
          res.send(createdMaterial);
        }
      }
      else{
        console.log(err);
      }
    })
})
```

here is where I send the request

```
fetch(url,{
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                owner: "Charlie",
                projectName: "Charlie's project"
            }
            })
```

I want to log the req.body, so I know that I can recieve the value and pass it as an argument to my function createProject.create().
I'm sending the request from a react client.

Comment: why `jsonParser` in `app.post`

Comment: I tried it before i copied it here, editing

Comment: try using application-type: application/json also while posting data

Comment: where should i put it?

Comment: In header key. eg  header {'Accept': 'application/json}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON needs to be passed as `body`

Something like

`body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header`

Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```
var url = 'https://example.com/profile';
var data = {username: 'example'};

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be `string` or {object}!
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(res => res.json())
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
.then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
```

Comment: How should I parse it when I recieve it in the API?

Comment: I assume you are dealing with JSON. `JSON.parse` should work if its a valid JSON string.

Comment: with body parser?

Comment: I think `bodyparser.json` will parse for you.. body should just have an object with your JSON decoded into an Object literal.

Comment: I still get an empty object {},
tried both app.use(bodyParse.json()) and adding bodyParse.Json() into the post method

Comment: The first thing I would do is double check what your fetch is sending, this is easily done in Chrome,.  In the network inspect just double check your sending what you expect to be sending.

Comment: I had syntax error in the headers in the fetch method, now it works. Thanks!!
You made my day!